# One Ubuntu two ROS System

Tags: ros, ros-diamondback, hector-quadrotor, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, just wanna ask, is it possible two have more than 2 ROS system on one Ubuntu system?
Example Ubuntu will both have fuerte and electric.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44724/one-ubuntu-two-ros-system/) by [ROS_NOOB_CYBORG](https://answers.ros.org/users/3275/ros_noob_cyborg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-09-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sure. You can have all ros distros installed in parallel. You can switch between them by sourcing the different setup.bash files. Just make sure you create separate [overlays](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays) for different ros distros.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2012-09-28**:
Also in this case, you should not source setup.sh in your .bashrc, but decide every time you open a new shell which distro you want to use, and source the corresponding setup.sh. Swithcing between distros in the same shell can cause errors.